# Amazon AWS IAM Returns 302 on POST request (signature version 2)

Tags: amazon-web-services

This is my exact request: minus credentials (throw away key and cert)

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: iam.amazonaws.com
cache-control: no-cache
connection: close
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Falcraft CMF

AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Action=UploadServerCertificate&CertificateBody=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----&Path=/&PrivateKey=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----&ServerCertificateName=testCertificate1&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-03-08T03:13:56.000Z&Version=2010-05-08&Signature=XXXX
```

Here is my exact reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
x-amzn-RequestId: b036aa40-a66f-11e3-9c2e-71bc7ad65b2e
Location: http://aws.amazon.com/iam
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 08 Mar 2014 03:13:57 GMT
```

I've looked quite a bit at my code, request, and google, but haven't found anything substantial to this problem.

Comment: I've tried duplicating the headers in the example posted here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_UploadSigningCertificate.html  However, it still doesn't work.  In fact when I 'hurl.it' to post to iam.amazonaws.com it spits back a 302.  I've also tried signature version 4.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

Make sure you put a content-length header in your POST request (yeah, I know, overlooked it)

The content-length header must be the length of your request urlencoded!

urlencode your request (body) as well.

Then you should get a 200.

Hope this helps someone!